# Added Wishlist to "My Account" page wooCommerce - Issues

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a wishlist link to the "My Account" page using the following online tutorial:
https://gist.github.com/nickmeagher/6576611103c50c8e3725a1693e717dcc

I am coming across two issues:

1: when I remove an item or add an item to cart the "My Account" sidebar does not remain and the wishlist takes up a whole page.

Initially the wishlist URL is: **example.com/my-account/wish-list/**

Remove an item / add an item to cart and the wishlist URL becomes: **example.com/wishlist/256cd8/**

How can a logged in user use the wishlist and ensure the My Account sidebar stays put?

Can anyone help with the first issue? Thanks for any input.

(Using the OceanWP theme & TI WooCommerce wishlist plugin if that helps)

---

<s>2: The wishlist link on the "My Account" page has an icon which is set through:</s>

```
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation ul li.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--wishlist a:before {
    content: '\e005';}
```

I have tried adding switching e085 to display a heart icon e005 but nothing happens.

[Update]: I have figured part 2 out: here is the solution:

```
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation ul li a:before {
    content: '\e08a';}
```

Comment: what icon pack is the Theme using ?? Font Awesome or other custom icon packs ? That should help you figure out why the icon is not showing. When you change the content does it come like a square icon ?

Comment: Thanks Bhanu...I'm not sure,  think it is using simple-line-icons / glyphicon.  I have tried using font awesome icons and nothing happens either.  It's the only page (My Account), I have an issue with, no problem with icons on any other part of the site.....j

Comment: Okay, figured out the icon part, thanks for your input @Bhanu, I should have used: .woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation ul li a:before {
    content: '\e08a';}

Comment: great, you were able to figure it out. For your 1st question can you switch back to storefront theme and rule out the plugins being responsible for this behaviour. once that happens you can actually figure out which of the both is responsible for the issue. I guess its a PRO theme so its impossible to for me to create a local setup to test this. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Bhanu, ill have to try that.